# How do I create a class where one attribute is a function chosen from one of several functions?

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning OOP principles in Python by making a calculator and I'm not sure about how to proceed with the design I've chosen or really what design to choose. My question is more about OOP in Python than it is about a calculator, but I'm using it as an example because that's what I'm working on.

Question: How might I go about defining a class where one of its attributes is a function which returns a one of several possible functions and doesn't have access to the others. For example:

```
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.operation = select_operation(symbol)

    def select_operation(symbol):
        if symbol == '+':
            return add
        elif symbol == '-':
            return subtract
        elif symbol == '*':
            return multiply
        else:
            return divide

    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(a, b):
        return a * b

    def divide(a, b):
        return a / b
```

Expected result:

```
plus = Operator('+')
plus.symbol
'+'
plus.operation
add
plus.add(2, 3)
5
plus.subtract(2, 3)
doesn't have access to subtract function
```

I was thinking class methods could be used here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. What do you mean "is this a good use-case for a class method". What do you have in mind, exactly? What are you referring to exactly? Do you mean *instance* methods, or are you specifically asking about `@classmethod`?

Comment: I hope that makes more sense. It's hard when I don't know what I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some details, it is a possible way. The details is that the actual operations should not be public members. If they are you have no way to prevent them to be used. So I would change your code to:

```
class Operator:
    _name = {'+': 'add', '-': 'substract', '*': 'multiply', '/': 'divide'}
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.operation = self._select_operation(symbol)
        setattr(self, self._name[symbol], self.operation)

    @staticmethod
    def _select_operation(symbol):
        return getattr(Operator, '_' + Operator._name[symbol])

    @staticmethod
    def _add(a, b):
        return a + b

    @staticmethod
    def _subtract(a, b):
        return a - b

    @staticmethod
    def _multiply(a, b):
        return a * b

    @staticmethod
    def _divide(a, b):
        return a / b
```

You can now do:

```
>>> op = Operator('+')
>>> op.operation(2, 3)
5
>>> op.add(2, 3)
5
>>> op.substract(3, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    op.substract(3, 1)
AttributeError: 'Operator' object has no attribute 'substract'
```

But IMHO it is not really the OOP way. I would create an Operator class and subclasses for the various operations. Then we could use a factory method to give the object of the appropriate subclass, or directly tweak the `__new__` special method:

```
class Operator:
    def __new__(cls, symbol):
        return super().__new__(cls._name[symbol])

class Adder(Operator):
    @staticmethod
    def operation(a, b):
        return a + b

class Substracter(Operator):
    @staticmethod
    def operation(a, b):
        return a - b

class Multiplyier(Operator):
    @staticmethod
    def operation(a, b):
        return a * b

class Diviser(Operator):
    @staticmethod
    def operation(a, b):
        return a / b

Operator._name = {'+': Adder, '-': Substracter, '*': Multiplyier, '/': Diviser}
```

Again we can do:

```
>>> op = Operator('+')
>>> op.operation(2, 3)
5
```

but here I have never defined an `add` method...

Answer (score 0):

`add`, `subtract`, etc. should be stand-alone functions, because they don't depend on anything in the object. Luckily, those functions are defined in the `operator` module:

```
import operator

# Use a dict to select the function.
OP_FUNCS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}


class Operator:

    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.operation = OP_FUNCS[symbol]


plus = Operator('+')
print(plus.symbol)
print(plus.operation)
print(plus.operation(2, 3))
```

Output:

```
+
<built-in function add>
5
```

I don't think you should add an `add` method to the object. The operation is already fully defined by `__init__`. If the caller doesn't know how it created the object, it won't know which method to call anyway.